# vite build bloating with assets not required

Tags: vite, msw

I have a vite app with react where i am using mui, aws amplify, MSW and other bits.

much of this is used in production while rest not.

e.g :

1. MSW is not used in production
2. aws amplify i am using only for auth.

I would like the msw and graphql assets to not included in the build as i do not use them.

they are dev deps so i expect they shouldnt be introduced in the first place.

what i am i missing?

adding the vite config and build output below

```
npm run build

> front-end@0.0.0 build
> tsc && vite build

vite v4.2.1 building for production...
✓ 1268 modules transformed.
Generated an empty chunk: "@popperjs".
Generated an empty chunk: "dom-helpers".
Generated an empty chunk: "prop-types".
dist/index.html                                    4.14 kB
dist/manifest.json                                 8.64 kB
dist/assets/@popperjs-4ed993c7.js                  0.00 kB │ gzip:  0.02 kB
dist/assets/dom-helpers-4ed993c7.js                0.00 kB │ gzip:  0.02 kB
dist/assets/prop-types-4ed993c7.js                 0.00 kB │ gzip:  0.02 kB
dist/assets/has-tostringtag-7c6352d6.js            0.17 kB │ gzip:  0.15 kB
dist/assets/has-ab8e2922.js                        0.18 kB │ gzip:  0.16 kB
dist/assets/web-encoding-2879efe2.js               0.19 kB │ gzip:  0.13 kB
dist/assets/gopd-28197985.js                       0.21 kB │ gzip:  0.19 kB
dist/assets/@open-draft-63bd287e.js                0.24 kB │ gzip:  0.18 kB
dist/assets/clsx-1229b3e0.js                       0.36 kB │ gzip:  0.23 kB
dist/assets/available-typed-arrays-4c94948f.js     0.41 kB │ gzip:  0.27 kB
dist/assets/inherits-852715c0.js                   0.42 kB │ gzip:  0.24 kB
dist/assets/node-fetch-55622175.js                 0.45 kB │ gzip:  0.29 kB
dist/assets/is-generator-function-06dfaf9d.js      0.53 kB │ gzip:  0.32 kB
dist/assets/is-arguments-f536cdf8.js               0.54 kB │ gzip:  0.33 kB
dist/assets/for-each-f57c5052.js                   0.67 kB │ gzip:  0.36 kB
dist/assets/is-node-process-281a7dbb.js            0.67 kB │ gzip:  0.41 kB
dist/assets/@babel-5d790daf.js                     0.73 kB │ gzip:  0.41 kB
dist/assets/js-levenshtein-9359370c.js             0.83 kB │ gzip:  0.44 kB
dist/assets/function-bind-68631a08.js              0.83 kB │ gzip:  0.45 kB
dist/assets/call-bind-60613813.js                  0.92 kB │ gzip:  0.51 kB
dist/assets/which-typed-array-19cbfd13.js          0.94 kB │ gzip:  0.52 kB
dist/assets/is-typed-array-a947e66b.js             1.01 kB │ gzip:  0.57 kB
dist/assets/has-symbols-cd7870b9.js                1.08 kB │ gzip:  0.44 kB
dist/assets/outvariant-5f1d58d8.js                 1.30 kB │ gzip:  0.74 kB
dist/assets/is-callable-7492318c.js                1.38 kB │ gzip:  0.59 kB
dist/assets/ms-f6814399.js                         1.38 kB │ gzip:  0.65 kB
dist/assets/cookie-faca195b.js                     1.77 kB │ gzip:  0.80 kB
dist/assets/react-is-1aacdabe.js                   2.16 kB │ gzip:  0.79 kB
dist/assets/set-cookie-parser-949adb8f.js          2.23 kB │ gzip:  1.08 kB
dist/assets/hoist-non-react-statics-691fe6cb.js    2.65 kB │ gzip:  0.97 kB
dist/assets/strict-event-emitter-a6dfbf23.js       2.99 kB │ gzip:  1.15 kB
dist/assets/headers-polyfill-03d31d34.js           3.03 kB │ gzip:  1.28 kB
dist/assets/scheduler-04ce0582.js                  4.14 kB │ gzip:  1.80 kB
dist/assets/stylis-581c9ed0.js                     4.21 kB │ gzip:  1.95 kB
dist/assets/index-ddf6a34e.js                      4.25 kB │ gzip:  1.93 kB
dist/assets/debug-0ece428e.js                      4.70 kB │ gzip:  2.01 kB
dist/assets/path-to-regexp-c1c3c645.js             5.84 kB │ gzip:  2.28 kB
dist/assets/events-5f626723.js                     6.09 kB │ gzip:  2.08 kB
dist/assets/react-transition-group-f24e646a.js     6.42 kB │ gzip:  2.21 kB
dist/assets/get-intrinsic-0eec208d.js              7.95 kB │ gzip:  2.55 kB
dist/assets/react-d5f3edc4.js                      8.12 kB │ gzip:  3.07 kB
dist/assets/util-538c81a0.js                      12.18 kB │ gzip:  4.30 kB
dist/assets/@emotion-9bbeac6e.js                  18.02 kB │ gzip:  7.79 kB
dist/assets/axios-707ed124.js                     28.79 kB │ gzip: 11.49 kB
dist/assets/@xmldom-cc04739d.js                   33.56 kB │ gzip: 12.05 kB
dist/assets/msw-edeba2f8.js                       34.99 kB │ gzip: 13.00 kB
dist/assets/@mswjs-50ca91ab.js                    45.77 kB │ gzip: 12.54 kB
dist/assets/@mui-284b8714.js                     129.01 kB │ gzip: 39.83 kB
dist/assets/react-dom-7f665208.js                130.00 kB │ gzip: 41.80 kB
dist/assets/graphql-ee8ff538.js                  164.34 kB │ gzip: 41.68 kB
✓ built in 1.90s
```

vite config file

```js
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: 'jsdom',
        setupFiles: ['./src/setup.ts'],
    },
    build: {
        manifest: true,
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                manualChunks(id) {
                    if (id.includes('node_modules')) {
                        return id.toString().split('node_modules/')[1].split('/')[0].toString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is code splitting a requirement you have?